# Teamviewer 6 VPN corrupted after upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: vpn, windows-8

I upgraded my computer from Windows 7 x64 to Windows 8 x64 all went well except my Teamviewer VPN is now corrupted and won't finishing installing.

With Teamviewer installed and going into Options > Advanced > Clicking on install VPN it starts to install and then stops halfway through and says "A problem occured during the installation. The teamviewer adapter was not installed successfully on your system."

I have spent days trying to work this out it creates and unknown network adapter in my Device Manager. I am 100% certain it will be a permission problem on one the registry keys it used to have access to pre Windows 8 and that during the upgrade the keys had it's permissions removed and now TV can't not modify the key but how do I find the key. I have searched team and teamviewer and vpn in my registry and check the permissions on all those folders with no luck.

Maybe the clue is that the 'unknown adapter' that is installed, could that mean it was blocked by a windows registry key and not one of it's own, as in it needs to edit the windows registry key to give it a display name in my Device manager?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! The question you asked is not within the scope of this particular Stack Exchange website. Please refer to the [help pages](http://$SITEURL.com/help) to learn which questions are on- and off-topic.

Comment: maybe the driver is not signed, check with teamviewer support OR uninstall, download latest "build"(aka new UI and version changes) and install

Comment: No it's not that. I give up the issue for abit, but I have found that other VPN adapters either don't install, install as unknown adapters. The error is with the permissions in the registry which was trigged by the upgrade from Win7 to Win8. In particular I have found the system is the owner of all the keys from control HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} when it should have been adminstrators.